# Can my company stop me from working overtime?

Tags: overtime

I have been doing the same overtime for several years, my company now want to stop me from doing this and let other people do it who earn less money. Can they do this?

Comment: Have they explained why they are stopping you from working overtime? Do you suspect it's indeed just because they'd have to pay out less if your colleagues did it instead?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you might think that they could *not* limit your overtime. I assume you're still being paid for whatever 'normal' time you're expected to work? Could you clarify your question a little?

Comment: Are you contract or full time? Have you checked what the company policies are around overtime (the ones that are written down, if any... employee handbook, contract, etc.)?

Comment: There's currently a close vote on this for it being about "company-specific regulations, policies.." which I think technically applies but I can't imagine a situation where a company can't stop you from working any and all hours you want.

Comment: This might be a good question for Law SE as well as labor laws in your locale may apply.

Comment: The usual rules for overtime are (in my jurisdiction)that overtime needs to be ordered, hence you working (payable) overtime could be stopped by no longer ordering you to work overtime ...

Comment: Yes and there might be legal limits on the hours you can work overtime regardless of who you are working for.

Comment: As usual, if you ask if someone can do something you _must add a location tag_! I could write an answer to the question but it's pointless because it's not likely that you're covered by Swedish laws.

Comment: Which **region** are you located in and are you talking about **paid overtime**?

Comment: Yes and it is very common.

Comment: @BSMP In Germany (where they have strict limits on the maximum number of hours people are allowed to work) I knew an office which literally had the lights turning off, automatic shutdown on the PCs, &security walking the building to escort out any stragglers. Being a financial services company, this was not *just* about the hours-worked laws, but also to reduce opportunities for unsupervised people to commit fraud. Working excessive overtime (and objecting to anyone else doing the work instead) will be a **massive** red flag for potential fraud to your employers, so OP needs to consider that

Comment: There's a difference between "stopping you from working overtime" and "stopping paying you for working overtime". I guess the question is about the second one!

Comment: Did they pay the overtime and you now fear you are getting less money?

Comment: Could you edit the question to say what kind of work do you do? There may be certain restrictions in a region based on what industry you're in.

Comment: [This question is being discussed in meta:](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6132/61983)

Answer (score 109):

You need to check what's in your contract - but broadly speaking if this is overtime in the sense of being outside of your contracted hours then yes they can.

Comment: Not only can they, but it's a very typical budget-vs-pace of work decision to make in a business. Is the extra work accomplished in overtime worth the extra cost?

Comment: Not only can they, in some places that may *have* to depending on what hours are being worked, the nature of the work, rules such as those set down in the European Working Time Directive, agreements made with national or more local unions, ...., and any number of other reasons.

Comment: Note, that it's not they can prevent it (in that if you work it anyway, they have to pay you), just that the repercussions amount to insubordination, and could result in your termination.

Comment: @Anoplexian or as it works in my company, you'll be unable to book any hours beyond the ones stated in your contract without explicit permission from your manager, the software simply won't accept your timesheet if you go over that number.

Comment: @Anoplexian reaaaallly epends on contract, not a legal thing. My contract says "you work for us 40 hours a week and we pay you x"  and if I decide to work more on my own then I'm pretty much breaching contract.

Comment: @Borgh: It is definitely a legal thing. In virtually all jurisdictions, labor law is binding.  Laws cannot be modified by employment contract terms. And for instance in my jurisdiction (Netherlands), if you consistently work overtime, that by law becomes an established right. Contracts can not deviate from that.

Comment: @Borgh If I tell you that I'll pay you $100 to stand outside my store twirling a sign for 8 hours, and you decide to stand outside my store twirling a sign for 12, you're not "breaching contract", you're simply engaging in volunteer sign-twirling. I have no obligation to pay you "overtime".

Comment: @DavidSpillett There are other situations too - in US federal government contracting, the contractor is often legally required to pay overtime to employees who work it, and also legally required to not spend any money beyond what is approved by the contract. A legal out for the company to deal with an employee taking unapproved overtime is to pay the employee and not charge the government - eating the cost. So that's why taking unapproved overtime can be grounds for termination - it's kind of stealing from the contractor.

Comment: @Acccumulation In at least some jurisdictions (I believe this is generally true in the US), the employer owes wages for any work performed. [You have to pay even for unauthorized overtime](https://www.tsheets.com/resources/overtime-laws-unauthorized-employee) if the employee does the work. It's up to you as the employer to affirmatively enforce a "no unauthorized overtime" rule; you can't just wait for four hours and enjoy the benefit of the sign-twirling without paying for it or putting a stop to it.

Comment: @Acccumulation: Also, in the US it's illegal for any for-profit business to accept volunteer labor.

Comment: @ZachLipton So, essentially, in such a jurisdiction, the company's only options are to either fire the employee or physically escort them out of the building at 5pm each day? That's completely ridiculous. (Not shooting the messenger, of course.)

Comment: @Kundor In this scenario, the employer isn't "accepting" volunteer labor. The labor is being done without any involvement from them.

Answer (score 45):

Yes they can do this.  I used to work at a company where some employees were purposefully doing unnecessary overtime work as a means to make more money.  The company took notice of this and required any overtime work to be first approved by a manager.  The extra hours that these employees were working was not worth the extra salary that the company had to pay them.  This is likely the reason why your company is allowing your coworkers that are currently making less money to work overtime.  It is a necessary overtime and they want to pay the least amount possible for it.

Comment: "It is a necessary overtime and they want to pay the least amount possible for it." I wouldn't make that assumption. Often, employees who earn less need extra money, so it could be that employees asked for overtime work, OP was hogging it all and business responded by trying to spread it out amongst all interested employees.

Answer (score 12):

Unless you're covered by a contract that says otherwise, yes, they can do that. The company is not under any obligation to grant you overtime (even if they've granted it in the past). If they want people who get paid less to do it instead, that's their prerogative.

Answer (score 8):

No they can't. (if you live in the Netherlands.)

If you work more hours then what's in your contract for a prolongued time, then after 13 weeks there's a legal presumption that your actual worktime is longer then what's in your contract and the employer has to schedule you for the average of hours you made in the 13 weeks.

Something that is very common in the Netherlands is that in the Care industry a lot of women  have 24 hour contracts, 3 days/week.
What often arises is staff shortage and you see people on a 24 hour contract working 32 or even 40 hours for years on end.

To protect those kind of employees from for instance punishment by employer (I will cut your hours for ....) but also for unemployment benefits. (If you work 40 hours for years but only 24 in your contract, you want to make sure unemployment benefits are calculated on 40 hours work.)

I made this answer because you don't specify where you live, and the law is wildly different from country to country.

So what you have to do is: consult a lawyer.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified a location nor any relevant information from your contract, so we can't say if they can or can't. But in most cases, yes they can, or rather you can't just work overtime unless specifically told to work overtime. In the vast majority of situations whether or not to work overtime is not the employee's decision.

Think about it, does it make sense for someone to mow their neighbour's lawn and demand payment for it? No, so then why should it be normal to do work outside your specified hours and expect to get compensated? If nobody asks you to work more than your contractually obligated hours there's really no reason to expect that it's allowed or wanted.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "your overtime" it is work required by the company for which someone might need to do overtime to complete.  So yes, they can allocate that work to whomever they want.

But more importantly you need to pay attention to why this is happening.

I've seen toxic management use overtime as a bonus for toxic behaviour (like spying on staff on behalf of management and being rewarded with overtime).  I've also seen toxic staff hold on to overtime and "hog it" not letting other staff have a chance of getting it for a bit of extra money.  When overtime is involved a lot of corruption can happen.

Your manager could be avoiding potential corruption allegations by sharing it around rather than let you have all of it.

Answer (score -1):

As the other answers, yes they can.

But, what happens if the situation arises where that work is not getting completed due to the lack of experience and they want you to come back to do overtime? Obviously "overtime" is not compulsory...

Perhaps then you get to negociate, saying "I'm used to having more free time now..., so how are you going to motivate me to come back to overtime" ?

Comment: I don't understand your conclusion that "overtime is not compulsory". If the company demands you to work overtime, and you choose to extort them instead, they'd be well within their rights to fire you.

Comment: @NuclearWang a company can **ask** you to work overtime, "overtime" being hours considered extra to the contracted hours. To whit, you don't have to accept to do them... They can't **force** you to do overtime - unless there are some specific clauses in your contract - which one hopes, you would have read,....

Comment: @NuclearWang In fact, I had this where I was on a contract that was 40 hours per week, with overtime sanctioned only by a manager. They had a weekend to do a stock-check which they asked all the employees to come in on overtime to complete it. It was cheaper than loosing two days of business especially when considering the impact on the customers...

Comment: An employer can't really ever *force* you to do anything, it's not like they can chain you to your desk and make you keep working. Overtime isn't ever compulsory in the sense that "we will make you do this whether you like it or not", but it can be compulsory in the sense that "we will fire you if you don't do this". A company can ***tell*** (not ask) you to work overtime and give you the boot if you decline. That of course doesn't happen in all cases of overtime, but I don't see anything that indicates whether overtime is optional or not here.

Comment: @NuclearWang: That definitely depends on the location.  In the US most employees are "at will" so yes the company can fire you for virtually any reason.  In many European countries however it would take gross misconduct to be fired.

Comment: As an employee, I would not play both sides of the coin.  The original poster clearly wants overtime; they can not logically want overtime and ask for the company to "motivate them to come back to overtime".  This type of behavior would either be spiteful or extortive.

Comment: If the employer were to regularly change the amount of hours someone works during a typical week, though, I would consider that objectional (Assuming a specified number of hours stated in the contract). Unless stated in the contract, one cannot be reasonably expected to regularly rearrange the structure of their personal life at their employers whims.That said, I wouldn't be surprised if such practices are lawful and can lead to termination if an employee objects to them.

Comment: *...one cannot be reasonably expected to regularly rearrange the structure of their personal life at their employers whims.* @Sazanami You just described all retail/service industry in the United States.

Answer (score -6):

They can, you may have to find a new task that only you can do. I'm lucky that where I work we have unlimited overtime. The industry as a whole has been short-handed for over 15 years. 65 to 70 plus hours per week. I love it!

Comment: I'm not sure this boasting is actually useful to the OP.

Comment: @GregoryCurrie  Agreed it is not helpful at all but it sounds more like thinly veiled sarcasm than boasting.

Comment: This doesn't address the question.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Apparently not thin enough for me!