# Budgeted overtime withdrawn

Tags: salary, overtime

Have worked overtime for last five years. Money was allocated for this to continue for another year. Been informed that this will now stop early May. Certain monetary remuneration was expected. Sudden change in income. Have been offered a loan to help if I am to be in difficulties. What are my rights?

Comment: Please include what country you're in as local laws will most likely effect this. You should be getting paid for any work you are doing and ideally how this situation would be handled would have already been discussed.



Could you include some more detail about what the situation you are in, it is fairly vague at the moment.

Comment: Start with reading your contract.

Comment: Are you in a union?

Comment: Without knowing where you're located? Which jurisdiction applies? If you're an exempt employee or not? What does your contract say? And whether or not they're asking you to work overtime anyway? We can't really answer your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my company stop me from working overtime?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/135843/can-my-company-stop-me-from-working-overtime)

Comment: *What are my rights?* Unless you have some kind of contract that says otherwise, odds are "none at all." They're probably not required to give you overtime if they don't want to.

Answer (score 7):

> What are my rights?

In most places, you right is to be paid for the work that you do.  If you are no longer going to be paid for overtime work then I would stop working overtime immediately.

Also, keep in mind that overtime is not supposed to be a regular occurrence.  If you are consistently working overtime, then either you:

- are not being given sufficient time to complete your tasks
- are not working as efficient as possible
- are padding your hours for extra income

The fact that you mention a "sudden change in income" is troubling.  Overtime pay should never be a significant part of your income.  If it is, then you need to re-evaluate your role at your company and the work that you are doing.  If you are actually doing so much extra work, you will burn yourself out eventually.

Comment: The bottom line is that if overtime is no longer being offered there isn't much you can do about that fact. 
 *You really should never count on overtime salary to pay your bills*  Likewise, since overtime is no longer being paid, you are free to stop working those overtime hours.

Comment: It's always a good idea to not spend all of one's income; but, many people forget that they should also plan their finances properly.  You can't depend on "extras" for savings or retirement, as they are not guaranteed, even if they are frequent and dependable.

Comment: Another reason for overtime: the employer wants to keep head count down, so uses overtime instead of hiring people.

Comment: I can appreciate the perspective this answer is written from, but I feel like it's a little strongly worded and ignores the truth of many workplaces. It's common for blue collar hourly jobs to have "expected" overtime. Some union contracts go as far as *requiring* overtime, and specify significant conditions that must be met before it's taken away. Yes, we should never count on overtime, but losing 10 hours a week of 1.5x pay basically means you're losing a third of your salary. It's a big deal and I don't think it's appropriate to indirectly shame someone who expects it or wants on it.

Comment: Overtime payments have just always been an extra. I have never used them to pay my bills. I actually put all the monies received into my pension. I thought this would come under 'Custom and Practice'. The allocated money is there for our financial year, Oct. - Sept. Can they really stop it just when they please?